# Flash Project Compiling without Flash IDE

Tags: flash

Is it possible to compile a Flash project without the use, or presence, of the Flash IDE?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flashdevelop to compile as3 Flex projects.

Flex sdk is free and open source, Flex Builder is not.
You can use Flashdevelop and Flex sdk to build actionscript projects if you don't want to buy Flash or Flex builder.

Comment: But would you then still need Flex?

Comment: @Jacques: For developing Flex application, yes; for developing a Flash application, no.

Answer (score 2):

Technically all you need to compile a SWF is a text editor and the [flex compiler](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads). Download and unzip the flex sdk (which contains the flex compiler), write up some code, and compile the code into a swf using the command line. Something like (note there are a lot of command line [options](http://www.docsultant.com/site2/articles/flex_cmd.html) that can be passed to the compiler):

```
path_to_flex_sdk/bin/mxmlc -file-specs path_to_document_class.as -o path_to_output.swf
```

As xxiaojun mentioned [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6956) is a free, open-source actionscript editor that does a nice job at keeping things simple, but it is Windows compatible only. It comes with build/run scripts, project and class templates, code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CodeDrive](http://codedrive.com/), flash/actionscript 3 IDE based on Visual studio